# How can I make a Generic PreferenceKey in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want make a **Generic PreferenceKey**, which I got 2 issues with my codes.

First I need define **()** for **T**, for using normal type like **String**, **Int** as **String()** or **Int()** so I need ***memberwise initializer*** for **T**.

Second Xcode complain that my **PreferenceKey** does not conform to **Equatable**, while I did it!  **<T: Equatable>**

How can I solve this 2 issues? thanks

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var stringOfText: String = "Hello, world!"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(stringOfText)
            .preference(key: CustomPreferenceKey.self, value: stringOfText)
            .onPreferenceChange(CustomPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in print(newValue) }
        
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomPreferenceKey<T: Equatable>: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: T { get { return T() } }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout T, nextValue: () -> T) { value = nextValue() }
    
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a possible approach to move with. Tested as worked with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

```
protocol Initable {
    init()
}

extension String: Initable {
}

struct CustomPreferenceKey<T: Equatable & Initable>: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = T

    static var defaultValue: T { get { T() } }

    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var stringOfText: String = "Hello, world!"

    var body: some View {

        Text(stringOfText)
            .preference(key: CustomPreferenceKey<String>.self, value: stringOfText)
            .onPreferenceChange(CustomPreferenceKey<String>.self) { newValue in print(newValue) }
    }
}
```

Comment: why we need **typealias Value = T**?, it works even with T and not using **Value**